# Add document sharepoint using web service Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I have an account entity in my **Microsoft Dynamics CRM** and the every account I have **folder in Sharepoint** which contains documents of this account I want to **create app on c#** using **Web Services CRM IOrganizationService** to Add Documents in SharePoint.
it's possible ?
Please any links to do that.
I need to help.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your Question what is understood is that you have setup `SharePoint` in CRM `Document Management System`.  You must have enabled `Document Location for Accounts` in the `Document Management Settings`.  Now you want to `Create/Upload` documents to the `Sharepoint Library`.  You can use `Sharepoint: Client Side Object Model(CSOM)` to do that. I have a piece of code that creates documents in sharepoint:

```
//Main Section Code
string sharePointUrl = GetDefaultSPSiteUrlFromCRMSiteCollectionEntity();
SharePointMethods sharePointMethods = new SharePointMethods(sharePointUrl, spUsername, spPassword, spDomain);

ClientContext context = sharePointMethods._clientContext;
Web web = sharePointMethods._clientContext.Web;
FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
  newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(newTempCRFDocumentFile);
  newFile.Url = sharePointFolder.ServerRelativeUrl+ CRFfileGeneratedName;
  newFile.Overwrite = true;
  List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Account");
  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = sharePointFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
  context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Helper Functions:

```
internal string GetDefaultSPSiteUrlFromCRMSiteCollectionEntity()
    {
        try
        {
            ConditionExpression c = new ConditionExpression("isdefault", ConditionOperator.Equal, true);
            FilterExpression f = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
            f.Conditions.Add(c);

            QueryExpression q = new QueryExpression("sharepointsite");
            q.Criteria = f;
            q.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("sharepointsiteid", "name", "absoluteurl", "relativeurl", "isdefault", "parentsite");

            EntityCollection crmSites = GRID.CRM.Common.Common.RetrieveMultiple(q);
            if (crmSites.Entities.Count > 0)
            {
                Entity defaultSharePointSite = crmSites.Entities[0];
                if (defaultSharePointSite.Attributes.Contains("parentsite") && defaultSharePointSite.Attributes.Contains("relativeurl"))
                {
                    Entity parentSiteOfDefaultSite = GRID.CRM.Common.Common.RetrieveSingle("sharepointsite", ((EntityReference)defaultSharePointSite["parentsite"]).Id);
                    return (string)parentSiteOfDefaultSite["absoluteurl"] + "/" + defaultSharePointSite.GetAttributeValue<string>("relativeurl");
                }
                else
                {
                    return defaultSharePointSite.GetAttributeValue<string>("absoluteurl");
                }
            }
            // no SharePoint Sites defined in CRM
            throw new Exception("CRM does not have any default SharePoint Sites");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("CrmMethods -> GetDefaultSPSite (" + ex.Message + ")");
        }
    }


internal class SharePointMethods
{
    string _siteUrl;
    public ClientContext _clientContext;
    internal SharePointMethods(string spSiteUrl, string spUsername, string spPassword, string spDomain)
    {
        try
        {
            _siteUrl = spSiteUrl;
            _clientContext = new ClientContext(_siteUrl);

            _clientContext.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
                (spUsername, spPassword, spDomain);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("SharePointMethods.Constructor --> [" + ex.Message + "]");
        }
    }
}
```