# Upload document to Microsoft Dynamics CRM integrated with Sharepoint

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to be able to upload a document created totally outside Sharepoint and CRM into the CRM document management system on the associated Sharepoint site. By the way it is Microsoft Dynamics CRM online. I have searched high and low, asked Sharepoint experts, called Microsoft Support but cannot find a solution. The document is created dynamically, probably in some sort of batch process, so this needs to be handled programmatically. The application is written in C# and I want, after creating the document, to find the relevant Sharepoint folder within the CRM system, which will be under one of the account entities, and upload it there. The one solution I did come across is this:

[Add document sharepoint using web service Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405178/add-document-sharepoint-using-web-service-microsoft-dynamics-crm)

Which seems promising but I can't get it to work. Has anyone ever done anything like this before?

Comment: How is this CRM Online and CRM 2011?